# Udp connection port 25000 returns no data

Tags: python-3.x, udp, python-sockets

I want to receive data from uk.tcpvpn.com on port 25000 udp
I have tried this code but no way i did not receive data

```
import socket, struct, time, math
from math import pi
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(struct.pack("dddddd",0,0,0,0,0,0), ("uk.tcpvpn.com", 25000))
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
sock.close()
print(data)
```

But when i tried with dns servers like 8.8.8.8 port 53 i get data
Is there a solution ?

Comment: Is there something listening on port `25000` at the host `uk.tcpvpn.com`? And are you sure it's UDP and not TCP? What documentation do you have that this should work? What is it you expect from this?

Comment: Yes i am sure i scanned it online on a site and i use it in openvpn udp